# Proving an Identity from Vector Calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields, fluid-dynamics

Say I have \begin{align*}
p\equiv & p(\textbf{x},t),\text{ pressure}\\
\textbf{e}\equiv& \text{ any fixed vector}\\
\rho\equiv& \rho(\textbf{x},t),\text{ mass density}\\
\textbf{u}\equiv& \textbf{u}(\textbf{x},t),\text{ the velocity of the fluid particle}
\end{align*}

I have to show that
$$-\operatorname{div}(p\textbf{e}+\rho\textbf{u}(\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{e}))=-\operatorname{div}(\rho\textbf{u})\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{e}-\rho(\textbf{u}\cdot\nabla)\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{e}-(\nabla p)\cdot\textbf{e}$$

Now what I have done so far is
\begin{align*}
&-\operatorname{div}(p\textbf{e}+\rho\textbf{u}(\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{e}))\\
=& -\operatorname{div}(p\textbf{e})-\operatorname{div}(\rho\textbf{u}(\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{e}))\\
=&-p\operatorname{div}(\textbf{e})-(\nabla p)\cdot\textbf{e}-\rho(\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{e})\operatorname{div}(\textbf{u})-\nabla(\rho(\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{e}))\cdot\textbf{u}\\
=&-p\operatorname{div}(\textbf{e})-(\nabla p)\cdot\textbf{e}-\rho(\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{e})\operatorname{div}(\textbf{u})-(\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{e})\textbf{u}\cdot\nabla\rho-\rho\textbf{u}\cdot\nabla(\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{e})\\
=&-p\operatorname{div}(\textbf{e})-(\nabla p)\cdot\textbf{e}-(\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{e})(\rho \operatorname{div}(\textbf{u})+\textbf{u}\cdot\nabla\rho)-\rho\textbf{u}\cdot\nabla(\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{e})\\
=&-p\operatorname{div}(\textbf{e})-(\nabla p)\cdot\textbf{e}-(\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{e})\operatorname{div}(\rho\textbf{u})-\rho\textbf{u}\cdot\nabla(\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{e})
\end{align*}

If everything is done correctly thus far, then it seems it's almost there.

Is the first term above zero? Also is the last term above same as the second term of what I need to show?

Comment: FYI - use `\operatorname{div}` to get the font/spacing correct with $\operatorname{div}$.  Compare, eg, $pdiv$ with $p\operatorname{div}$.

Comment: All that's left is to note that $\mathbf{e}$, being a fixed vector, has zero divergence. Then it's just a rearrangement of terms.

Comment: @Semiclassical thanks. also are $\rho\textbf{u}\cdot\nabla(\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{e})$ and $\rho(\textbf{u}\cdot\nabla)\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{e}$ the same?

Comment: Yes. For a simple case, take $\mathbf{u}=(u_x,y_y)$ and a scalar function $f$. Then \begin{align}
\mathbf{u}\cdot (\nabla f)
&=(u_x,u_y)\cdot(\partial_x f,\partial_y f)\\
&=u_x \partial_x f+u_y\partial_y f\\
&=(u_x \partial_x +u_y \partial_y)f\\
&=(\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla)f
\end{align}
So it amounts to either taking the dot product with the gradient vector, or (formally) with $\nabla$ itself.